# Separating values in list when it decrease and increase

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, list, multidimensional-array

This is what I would like to do.

I have huge number of number in a list, but it has a sequence of either increasing or decreasing.

Such as,
100 
200 
300
400
500
600
500
400
300
200
100
500
700
800
900

Lets say this values are stored in a list or maybe an array. How could I separate these to multiple arrays or list consisting of the sequence.

Such as, List 1: 100 200 300 400 500 600
List 2 :500 400 300 200 100
List 3:500 700 800 900

This is what I have done. I am stuck.

```
for (int i = 0; i < p.Count - 1; i++)
{
    double v = p.ElementAt(i);
    if (initialP > v)
    {
        if (low == 1)
        {
            sep.Add(sep_index);
            low = 0;
        }
        else
        {

        }
        high = 1;
    }

    if (initialP < v)
    {
        if (high == 1)
        {
            sep.Add(sep_index);
            high = 0;
        }
        low = 1;
    }
    initialP = v;
    sep_index++;

    if (i == p.Count - 2)
    {
        sep.Add(sep_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a list of lists, and a parsing list then loop through, if the next item in the list matches the current pattern, add it to the parsing list, otherwise add the parsing list to the list of lists and "reset it" to a new list

Comment: this is kind of a fun problem

Comment: oh god.. i have been trying that for quite some time Sayse.. i just cant figure it out.. can provide a small written algorithm for it? thx alot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should use a list of of lists and while looping use a new list when there is a switch in the direction of the sort:

EDIT: Fixed to take into account equal numbers and strict comparaisons.

```
    public static List<List<int>> GetLists(int[] nums, bool strict) { 
        List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        lists.Add(list);
        list.AddRange(nums.Take(1));
        if (nums.Length <= 1) {
            return lists;
        }
        if (strict && nums[0] == nums[1]) {
            list = new List<int>();
            lists.Add(list);
            list.Add(nums[1]);
        }
        else
            list.Add(nums[1]);


        if (nums.Length == 2)
        {
            return lists;
        }

        int direction = Math.Sign(nums[2] - nums[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < nums.Length; i++) {
            int d = Math.Sign(nums[i] - nums[i - 1]);
            if ((d == direction && (d != 0 || !strict))
                    || (d != 0 && strict)
                    || (Math.Abs(d + direction) == 1 && !strict))
            {
                list.Add(nums[i]);
                if (d != 0 && direction == 0) direction = d;
            }
            else
            {
                direction = d;
                list = new List<int>();
                list.Add(nums[i]);
                lists.Add(list);
            }
        }
        return lists;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4 };
        var lists = GetLists(nums, false);
        foreach (var list in lists) {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.Write(item + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        /*
         * Prints:
         * 2 2 2 1 1
         * 3 3 4 4
         * */
    }
```

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you very much... Its been a great help !!

Comment: Sorry, but "GetLists(new int[] {3, 2, 1});" seems to be a test fail: "[[3, 2, 1]]" is expected while "[[1]]" is actually got.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sorry, the first version works fine. Then I changed it to not test for Length == 0 and Length == 1 and Length == 2 (See past edits) I fixed it now.

Comment: Sorry again, but "GetList(new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4});" seems to be another test fail: the output is "[[2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [3], [3], [4], [4]]" where the first sublist accepts equal items ("2", "1") while the other sublists don't ("3", "4"). "[[2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [3, 3, 4, 4]]" is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Derivation, or spin. If it is positive -- one direction. Otherwise -- another.
Use spin, which will show you direction (up or down): (n+1/n). When spin changes, then store elements in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
private static List<int[]> SplitOnDirection(int[] input)
{
    List<int[]> output = new List<int[]>();
    List<int> currentList = new List<int>();

    bool? isRaising = null;
    int? previousNumber = null;

    foreach (int number in input)
    {
        // do we have a previous value?
        if (previousNumber.HasValue)
        {
            // only if the number is different, then we have to check the direction.
            if (number != previousNumber.Value)
            {
                bool isHigherNumber = (number > previousNumber.Value);

                // do we already know if we start with raise/lowering
                if (isRaising.HasValue)
                {
                    // if we have a higher number and we're not raising, change direction.
                    if (isHigherNumber != isRaising.Value)
                    {
                        // We changed direction..
                        output.Add(currentList.ToArray());
                        currentList = new List<int>();
                    }
                }

                isRaising = isHigherNumber;
            }
        }

        previousNumber = number;
        currentList.Add(number);
    }
    // if we didn't changed direction, we should 'flush' these.
    if (currentList.Count > 0)
        output.Add(currentList.ToArray());

    return output;
}

int[] input = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 500, 700, 800, 900 };

List<int[]> output = SplitOnDirection(input);
```

Comment: Sorry, but test call "SplitOnDirection(new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4});" returns strange "[[2, 2, 2, 1, 1] [3] [3] [4] [4]]":
as for the first sublist the equal values ("2", "1") are OK, while as for the others ("3", "4") are not

Comment: The result is right.  2,2,2,1,1 is lowering but 3,3,4,4 is raising. It gives two lists results. Probably just missed my update on `if (number != previousNumber.Value)`, so thats fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
    public static IList<IList<int>> UpDownSeparator(IEnumerable<int> value) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

      List<IList<int>> result = new List<IList<int>>();

      List<int> current = new List<int>();
      result.Add(current);

      // +1 - asceding, -1 - descending, 0 - to be determined later
      int direction = 0;

      foreach(int item in value) {
        if (direction == 0) {
          if (current.Count > 0) {
            if (item > current[current.Count - 1])
              direction = 1;
            else if (item < current[current.Count - 1])
              direction = -1;
          }

          current.Add(item);
        }
        else if (direction < 0) {
          if (item > current[current.Count - 1]) {
            direction = 1;
            current = new List<int>() { item };
            result.Add(current);
          }
          else
            current.Add(item);
        }
        else {
          if (item < current[current.Count - 1]) {
            direction = -1;
            current = new List<int>() { item };
            result.Add(current);
          }
          else
            current.Add(item);
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

....

  List<int> list = new List<int>() { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 500, 700, 800, 900};

  // [[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600], [500, 400, 300, 200, 100], [500, 700, 800, 900]]
  IList<IList<int>> result = UpDownSeparator(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Took around 20 min, but I would do something like this below. Using Java, I am sure could easily be written using other language syntax.

```
Input
1, 1, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9
Output
1 1 1 -1 
2 3 4 4 4 5 6 
5 4 4 3 3 
6 6 
2 1 
5 7 8 9
```

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = new int[]{1, 1, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9};
    List<List<Integer>> lists = split(input);
    for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.print(integer+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public static List<List<Integer>> split(int[] input) {
    List<List<Integer>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    if(input.length >= 1) {
        List<Integer> list = newList(listOfList, input[0]);
        Order lastO = null;
        int last = input[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            Order currentO = Order.getOrder(input[i], last);
            boolean samePattern = Order.sameDirection(currentO, lastO);

            if(lastO == null || samePattern) {
                list.add(input[i]);
            } else {
                list = newList(listOfList, input[i]);
                lastO = null;
            }

            if(currentO != Order.Equal){
                lastO = currentO;
            }
            last = input[i];
        }
    } 
    return listOfList;
}

private static List<Integer> newList(List<List<Integer>> listOfList, int element) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOfList.add(list);
    list.add(element);
    return list;
}


private static enum Order {
    Less, High, Equal;

    public static Order getOrder(int first, int second) {
        return first > second ? High : first < second ? Less : Equal;  
    }

    public static boolean sameDirection(Order current, Order last) {
        if(last == Order.Less && (current == Order.Less  || current == Order.Equal)) {
            return true;
        } else if(last == Order.High && (current == Order.High  || current == Order.Equal)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```